# How to check if key exists in a for loop in python using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to see if a business name matches with a previous business name and if it does break the iteration, if not continue with the iteration.

**The problem**

It is ignoring the break and I still see duplicates.

**run.py**

```
 def parse(self, response):
    for business in response.css('div.info'):
        business_names = business.css('span[itemprop="name"]::text').extract()
        business_name = business.css('span[itemprop="name"]::text').extract()

        if business_name in business_names:
            break
        else:
            website = business.css('div.links  a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            phone_number = business.css('div.phones.phone.primary::text').extract()
        yield {
            'Business Name': business_names,
            'Website': website,
            'Phone Number': phone_number,

        }
```

Comment: You iteration is not right.  You get item from business name and then check if equal.  That is not possible.

Comment: Can you add some sample data for the business names (or make some up if you don't want to name any real companies, just as long as the format of the data matches what you are seeing)

Comment: i didn't figure it out, i though it worked but i doesn't here is what i have so far

Answer (score 1):

I think business_names and business_name both are of list type and if you simply apply in operator it will return FALSE always. so better to use extract_first or any other logic while searching business_name in business_names.

Answer (score 0):

Check for existance using the `in` operator and have some value for item. Right now your code is checking to see if an element of `business_name` is equal to`business_name`

```
for item in business_name:
    if item == business_name:
        break
```

To:

```
if 'somevaluehere' in business_names:
    break
```

Comment: i think i might understand now, let me give this a shot

Comment: does this look more accurate `if business_name in business:
                break`

Comment: i get `TypeError: argument of type 'Selector' is not iterable`

Comment: i still dont understand mate

Comment: try printing out business_name to see what is in it. You're trying to find a value in that list....Actually reading your edit, you might just be wanting to check if business_name is equal to some value. Do you know what value you want it to be equal to?

Comment: `for item in business_names:
                if (item == " "):
                    print ("no business name")` the print doesnt appear

Comment: inside your main for loop just add `print (business_name)`

Comment: where  should i place this ?

Comment: this is the output i get and it doesnt print `'Business Name': []}`